# When to use FindAncestor?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

In the image below, why is FindAncestor needed and why is AncestorType not UserControl?

If the UserControl was inside a StackPanel, would AncestorType be StackPanel?

In other words, what does the parent control have to do with binding to the viewmodel.Message?  Why is all the other xaml needed in the Binding?

[image: WPF binding]

Comment: Shouldn't Base ViewModel be abstract and hence not anyone's DataContext at all?

Comment: Maybe Base isn't a good description.  If Both were 'Employee' View and ViewModel, does that make a difference?

Comment: Well, your diagram is misleasig, it looks as if ViewModel1 is related to the Base-ViewModel, e.g. it inherits from it. I think the boxes should be separate if that is not the case.

Comment: Ok, sorry.  I see what you are saying.  There are two DataContexts, Views and viewmodels involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't need to specify AncestorType=UserControl, since that's the default context.  If you omit the "RelativeSource" parameter, it will bind to the local DataContext.

In this case, the UserControl and the Window it is contained in must have different DataContexts.  Since a UserControl generally doesn't know the name of its parent at design time, you can at the least usually assume it's only going to be in a single Window and create a binding to the Window's DataContext using RelativeSource as shown.

This can be common because in an application, the Window might have a DataContext for information about the application as a whole, but the current UserControl might be focused on a particular piece of data (such as an Employee).  In this case all the default bindings point to the Employee, but the UserControl might want to bind to something in the parent DataContext too.

Answer (score 1):

Why is FindAncestor needed?
Here FindAncestor is used to access to the Window object to get an access to the DataContext of Window object.

Why is AncestorType not UserControl?
Because the DataContext of the UserControl object may be not the same as the DataContext of Window object.
Normally it's the same but you can redefine it.

If the UserControl was inside a StackPanel, would AncestorType be StackPanel?
No if the StackPanel is itself in your Window.
Don't forget that you target the Type of the graphical object that contain the DataContext you want.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the developer just knew that the object that had the datacontext they were looking for was a Window.  If, for example, a data context was set on a stackpanel and you wanted something from that datacontext, then you would use the AncestorType = Window.  Since there are two datacontexts, and the user wanted to bind something to the outside one, FindAncestor was used.